# OpenVPN to use VPC Subnet IP space

Tags: routing, openvpn, amazon-vpc

I have setup OpenVPN server in AWS VPC. But When client connects to to it it assign IP from `10.8.0.0/16` subnet. I want OpenVPN server to assign the IP to the client from Subnet IP space.

How this can be done ? What configuration I need to have for OpenVPN server.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend this. *Distinct networks* should use *distinct IP address ranges*.

However if you really want to do this and understand all the consequences (do you?) you can reserve a slice of the 10.2.0.0/16 VPC address range, e.g. 10.2.255.0/24 and use that for OpenVPN. You will have to add this to the VPC Route Table and point to the OpenVPN gateway instance in AWS.

You won't gain much if you do this, you still have to do all the setup, routing, firewalling, etc, same as if it was a distinct address space.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: That doesn't work.  You can't static route the space assigned to the VPC to an instance -- it can only be attached to ENIs.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot ok, I didn’t try. That answers the OP’s question then - it can’t be done.